# Scrapy + Splash don't click a button

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

the website shows 10 articles and then the user has to click a button "load more" and then, five new articles will loaded. But with Scrapy and Splash it doesn't work. So I downloaded the page with curl and this is the button:

```hmtl
<div class="kick__module-centered">
   <a class="kick__btn kick__btn-light kick__btn-text-up kick__btn-sm kick__btn--spinner kick__btn--spinner-gray3" href="javascript: void(0);"
      onclick="ov.toggle.expandTransfer(this, true);">
   load  more
   </a>
</div>
```

The splash code is:

```py
lua_script = """
function main(splash, args)
    -- Load the target webpage
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(1))
    splash.private_mode_enabled = false
    local max_clicks = 120  -- Maximum number of times to click the button
    local clicks = 0       -- Counter for the number of clicks

    while clicks < max_clicks do
        
        -- Find the element
        local element = splash:select('.kick__btn--spinner-gray3')
        
        -- Check if the element exists
        if element then
            element:mouse_click()  -- Click the button
            clicks = clicks + 1
            assert(splash:wait(0.5))  -- Wait for the page to respond to the click
            
        else
            break  -- Break the loop if the button is not found
        end
    end
    
    -- Return the HTML of the page after the clicks
     
    return {
        
        html = splash:html(),
        clicks = clicks  -- Return the number of clicks performed
    }
end
"""
```

With the code the button should be clicked for 120 times, but it is not clicked once. I have a similar case with another page and I use the same Splash code for the following button and it works:

```html
<div class="kick__modul__item kick__modul__item--expand kick__module-centered">
   <a class="kick__btn kick__btn-light kick__btn-text-up kick__btn-sm kick__btn--spinner kick__btn--spinner-gray3"
      href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="ov.toggle.expandNewsBlog(this, '@@newsblog:3000;[953155,958879,958916,959867,960837,963799,977053,981677,982156,982162,982170,982174,982486,982516,982521,982529,982588,982589,982606,982609,982618,982622,982623,982625,982627,982637,6000004862074,6000004862075,6000004862076,6000004862077,6000004862078,6000004862079,6000004862080,6000004862081,6000004862082];@@');">
   load more</a>
</div>
```

Why is the button of the first html-code not clicked? What can be a solution? I prefer not to use selenium.